# Porque no puedo crear dos subniveles dentro de un objeto?

Tags: poo, object, objeto

```
var objeto = {
   sub1_A: {},
   sub1_B: {},
   sub1_C: {}
}
```

No tengo problemas si hago lo siguiente:

```
objeto.sub1_A.sub2 = "Prueba";
```

Pero sí si desciendo un nivel más directamente:

```
objeto.sub1_A.sub2.sub3 = "Prueba";
```

Si intento setear lo anterior me dice "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'recodes' of undefined". Entiendo que es porque puedes setear/definir un metodo o propiedad de un objeto ya existente pero no de uno que no.

¿No hay un modo de bajar tantos niveles como quiera creando dicho "camino"?

Si quisiera crear algo como objeto.sub1.sub2.sub3.sub4.sub5="SetealoYa!" me veo obligado ir paso a paso? Estoy convencido de que debe de haber otro método.

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `objeto.sub1_A.sub2 = "Prueba";` dado que sub1_A es un objeto, este objeto lo definiste en tu objeto principal

```
var objeto = {
   sub1_A: {},// aquí definiste sub1_A como objeto
   sub1_B: {},
   sub1_C: {}
}
```

Cuando tu defines `sub2`, estás definidendo que `sub1_A` tiene una propiedad de tipo string llamada `sub2` cuyo valor es prueba.

Al hacer `objeto.sub1_A.sub2.sub3 = "Prueba";` te marca error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'recodes' of undefined` porque no existe una propiedad de sub1_A que sea sub2.

Esta propiedad tendría que ser un objeto para que pudiera tener otra propiedad. 
Entonces podrías hacer lo siguente.

```
objeto.sub1_A.sub2 = {};
objeto.sub1_A.sub2.sub3 = "prueba"
```

Si quisieras agregar un nivel más, tendrías que convertir sub3 en objeto, dado que no puedes agregar propiedades a un string.